# Disk utilization 100%, no read or write

Tags: raid-5, hardware-raid, utilization

Our disks on one of our servers are showing 100% utilization but no read or write.

here is the output of `iostat -xc 1` and errors on `syslog`
https://gist.github.com/4110533

status info from raid card `sudo tw-cli /c6 show`
https://gist.github.com/4110611

Latest firmware version is installed on raid card.
What may be the problem?

Comment: Are you using disks with [TLER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control) enabled? If not a disk might have an error and it will be trying to recover. 

No time limit on recovering makes sense for a regular consumer disks  since taking a long long time (even hours) is better than loosing data.  On RAID you do not want this. Instead you want the disk to fail and the data to be supplied from a working disk.

This assumes that the 3ware card does not just drop the while disk after it has not responded for a while. I am not sure which card you use and how that model acts.